# Cannot Implicity Convert Type in findResults.NextPageOffset

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am working on the code to retrieve Exchange email messages by batches of `100`.

```
SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults;
ItemView view = new ItemView(100);
int inboxCount = 1;
do
{
    findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sf, view);
    foreach (var item in findResults.Items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(inboxCount + ". " + item.Subject);
        inboxCount++;
    }

    //error below
    view.Offset = findResults.NextPageOffset;
}
while (findResults.MoreAvailable);
```

However, I encountered an error on `findResults.NextPageOffset;`, of the following:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Value`, which will give you the `int` from the `nullable int`

```
view.Offset = findResults.NextPageOffset.Value;
```

However there is a chance it's `null`, what do you do then? Well, that's up to you.

```
if(!findResults.NextPageOffset.HasValue)
   throw new InvalidOperationException("Oh dear...");
```

---

**Further Reading**

[Nullable types (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/)

> Use the Nullable.HasValue and Nullable.Value readonly properties
> to test for null and retrieve the value, as shown in the following
> example: if (x.HasValue) y = x.Value;

Comment: Thank you @TheGeneral. I tried your solution, and modified and include the above statement in my code in order. However, before it is able to reach the `if` statement, an error indicating that `Nullable object must have a value`.

Comment: @gymcode the check has to go before the call to `Value` the idea is to check if its null and deal with it first before accessing `Value`